# How to add arrays to an arraylist and get the result?

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist, onclick

I'm trying to add elements from this array

```
double[] priceInDouble={89.35, 55.95, 95.90, 60.00, 116.55, 75.10, 47.00, 18.05};
```

to the addedPrices ArrayList and get the sum of the same ArrayList with the following code, but no luck. Need help

```
ArrayList<Double> addedPrices = new ArrayList<Double>();
                for(int i = 0; i < 1 ; i++) {
                    addedPrices.add(i,priceInDouble[position]);
                    double price = 0;
                    for (double d :  addedPrices){
                        price +=d;
                        TextView textView = (TextView)activity.findViewById(R.id.counter_text);
                        textView.setText(NumberFormat.getInstance().format(price));
                        textView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Please search Stack Overflow before posting.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is a bit off, let's try to fix it:

```
ArrayList<Double> addedPrices = new ArrayList<>(priceInDouble.length);
double sum = 0;

for(i = 0; i < priceInDouble.length; i++){

    addedPrices.add(priceInDouble[i]); 
    sum += priceInDouble[i];
} 

/*I'm assuming you actually needed
the ArrayList and were not doing it just to add the 
values with a for-each loop.. */
```

So now you already have the sum when you're done moving the array.

Anyway, your code is very broken so please next time try to focus harder and look for information already on other answers before posting, what you were missing is basic logic/syntax that can be easily found online.